# fragment to fragment transaction is slow

Tags: android, fragment

I have one `fragment` with `ListView` at left side of Screen...
whenever user clicks on any item of `ListView` i show `fragment` at right side ..

Below is how I am using transaction:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
SiteDetailsFragmentActivity fragment = new SiteDetailsFragmentActivity();
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Why ds transaction is slow?

Comment: Transaction is not slow..May be its because of `ListView` takes time to load data. Try to load `ListView` data after `onCreateView()` of `fragment` i.e. using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: does list view contain images and if yes check size of images

Comment: @T-rush - m allowing user to click on items only if all data gets loaded...

Comment: Its nothing to do with user click. My suggestion is to load data of right `Fragment` in background after `onCreateView()` is executed.

Comment: @OAEI not helping me

Comment: Is there any images in Either on List items or backgroung of items or on  Fragment on which your fragment is being transitions.Check it once ....?

Answer (score 2):

There are some tips may be useful.

- if you have lots of work like network calls in your fragment try to call them after your onCreateView() function. i.e you can use onStart() or onResume() functions.Also, try to use multiThread.
- if you have Image Loading try to reduce image qualities or its size.[reduce image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)
- Also avoid animation in replacing your fragments.

  ```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
  ```