# low quality when resizing image in Android?

Tags: android, screen-size, resize-image

This is my code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.resizedView);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
        options.inScaled = false;
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tutimage1, options);
        Bitmap bmp = getResizedBitmap(largeIcon, 200);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize)
    {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }

       // return getResizedBitmapWithQuality(image, width, height);
        return  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    }
```

So I tried to research and tested but the result is still the same.

[image]
[image]

**Is that because of the size needed is too small?**

Original size is 1120 x 2048, the size of the result is 110 x 200.

Comment: Because you are decreasing height of image with 200. getResizedBitmap(largeIcon, 200);

Comment: is there a way to fix this issue?
Or should I force to increase height?
I need really size of 200.
Help me!!!

Comment: [Compress your image without losing quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android) I hope it's help full to you..

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to improve the image bitmap quality

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    float scaleX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float scaleY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float pivotX = 0;
    float pivotY = 0;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I think the size needed is too small.