# App gets incredible large because of a few images

Tags: android, image

I want to use in my app 10-15 images. After adding 5 images with the extension `Batch Drawable Import` my app is 78 MB large. Before adding the images it was 6 MB large.

The extension generates images for the different resolutions (hdpi, ldpi, ...). Every image in the xxhdpi folder is 10 - 14 MB large.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrease image size without losing its quality in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate of that post, that one handles the runtime case, this is the static APK case

Comment: What are you using the images for?

Comment: @stan0 the image are used to achive something like this: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d0/67/e9/d067e934dcf6c89633749637a12dd324--ios-ui-ui-ux.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding them to each bucket, put them in `drawable-nodpi`. May or may not work depending on what you use them for, but having images in that size in each bucket is not recommended. Otherwise I would just try to reduce the size by resizing and lowering quality. Images that large feels a bit overkill for most mobile devices (again, depends on what you use them for)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The images are used to achive something like this: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d0/67/e9/d067e934dcf6c89633749637a12dd324--ios-ui-ui-ux.jpg