# how can pass byte array one activity to another android

Tags: android, android-room, android-internal-storage

**How can pass byte array one activity to another android**

*is possible pass large byte array or bitmap or image pass from intent*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on size and kind of the data. You can pass it by your bundle intent but maybe you will have an exception of marshaling the array see doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException).Or You can pass an entire object from your application class like this:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
private Currency currencyMined;
public Currency getCurrencyMined(String name) {

    return PrefHelper.getObjectVal(name, Currency.class);
}

public void setCurrencyMined(String name, Currency currencyMined) {
    this.currencyMined = currencyMined;

}
```

Comment: how can decrease image size when we get image from gallery

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android